# Getting empty array on Laravel eloquent relationship HasManyThrough

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm making a sort of like reddit website.

I need query that would give me the profile of the user and his karmas through the threads that the user have made.

Tables and relationship:

> User has one profile
>    User has many threadKarmaPoints through threads

```
    public function threadKarmaPoints() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\ThreadKarmaView',
        'App\Models\ThreadView',
        'userId',
        'threadId',
        'userId',
        'threadId');
}
```

Query: (I need to get the user through username and not by id)

```
$user = UserView::where('username', $username)
            ->with(['profile', 'threadKarmaPoints'])
            ->firstOrFail();
```

This gives me empty array. Although if I remove the `'threadKarmaPoints'` in with, it gives me the user and his profile so I think there must be wrong with my `threadKarmaPoints` relationship.

Additional question: in eloquent query, should `->with()` comes first or `->where()`?

Comment: Make sure the 5th and 6th argument to `hasManyThrough` is right local keys

Answer (score 1):

```
 just remove Models from App  
    public function threadKarmaPoints() {
      return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\ThreadKarmaView',
        'App\ThreadView',
        'userId',
        'threadId',
        'userId',
        'threadId');
   }
```

second with or where in your problem doesn't change the meaning its OK

Comment: How would that fix my problem? The files are in models folder.

Comment: can you just try because if you are in laravel 5+ there is no model folder
beside you say that UserView::
is returned query without threadKarmaPoints
can you tell me the model use on top of your code like
use App\User;
if it use App\ModelName; then iam right if not can you tell me what it is

Comment: I created a model folder to organize my code. So no, it won't work.